# JButton disappears when GUI is clicked

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paint, actionlistener

I'm making checkers in java and the "New Game" button disappears when I click on the GUI. It reappears when I hover my mouse over it, but will disappear again if I click the GUI. Do you know what I did wrong/am doing incorrectly?

```
public void setFrame()
    {
        boardSize  = 10;
        squareSize = 50;
        int imageSize = boardSize * squareSize;       
        image = new BufferedImage(imageSize, imageSize, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        imageIcon = new ImageIcon(image);
        jLabel = new JLabel(imageIcon);
        button = new JButton("New Game");
        button.setFocusable(false);
        button.setBounds(375, 5, 100, 20);
        pnl = new JPanel();
        pnl.setBounds(400, 10, 200, 100);
        pnl.setLayout(null);
        pnl.add(button);

        jFrame = new JFrame("Checker Board");
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.add(jLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jFrame.add(pnl);
        jFrame.setSize(506, 558);
        jFrame.setResizable(false);
        jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);

        jFrame.validate();
    }

    /**
     * Paint the checker board onto the Image.
     */
    public void paint()
    {
        Graphics graphics = jFrame.getGraphics();

        pnl.paint(graphics);
        button.paint(graphics);

        graphics.setColor(Color.black);
        Font font = new Font("Score", Font.BOLD, 20);
        graphics.setFont(font);
        graphics.drawString("Score: ", 150, 47);
        graphics.drawString("Turn: ", 20, 47);
        graphics.setFont(font.deriveFont(0, 16.0F));
        graphics.drawString("Red: " + Game.score.getScoreRed() + "    Black: " + Game.score.getScoreBlack(), 230, 47);
        graphics.drawString((Game.redTurn ? "Red" : "Black"), 80, 47);

        // paint a red  board
        graphics.setColor(Color.red);
        graphics.fillRect(xShift, zShift, boardSize * squareSize, boardSize * squareSize);

        // paint the black squares
        graphics.setColor(Color.black);
        for (int row = 0; row < boardSize; row++)
        {
            for (int col = row % 2; col < boardSize; col += 2)
            {
                graphics.fillRect( row * squareSize + xShift, col * squareSize + zShift, squareSize, squareSize );
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                if(Game.board.pieces[i][j] != null)
                {
                    Color pieceColor = Game.board.pieces[i][j].getColor().equals(EnumTeam.BLACK) ? Color.gray : Color.pink;
                    graphics.setColor(pieceColor);
                    graphics.fillOval((i * 50) + 10 + xShift, (j * 50) + 10 + zShift, 30, 30);
                    if(Game.board.pieces[i][j].isKing())
                    {
                        pieceColor = Game.board.pieces[i][j].getColor().equals(EnumTeam.BLACK) ? Color.darkGray : Color.magenta;
                        graphics.setColor(pieceColor);
                        graphics.fillOval((i * 50) + 20 + xShift, (j * 50) + 20 + zShift, 10, 10);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        graphics.setColor(Color.cyan);
        drawRect(graphics, Game.board.getSelectedX(), Game.board.getSelectedZ(), 5);
    }
```

Comment: It will be much easier for us to help you if you only post relevant parts of your code, such as how the button is being created, the click events on the Panel/button/etc.

Comment: 1st bad approach `pnl.setLayout(null);` try to call `validate` after call `paint` and often say to don't paint in windows instead do paint in containers overriding `paintComponent`

Comment: Do not, ever use `Graphics graphics = jFrame.getGraphics();`!  This is not how custom painting is done in Swing.  The meare fact that you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not, **ever** use `Graphics graphics = jFrame.getGraphics();` (or `getGraphics` generally)!  This is not how custom painting is done in Swing.  The mere fact that you'v then cleared the graphics context is your core problem.

All painting should be done within the context of the painting API, preferably by overriding `paintComponent` from any component that extends `JComponent` (I, personally, prefer `JPanel`)

Create a custom component and use it it perform you custom painting.  Layout it out with your other components on the frame.

Set [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and  [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details about how painting works in Swing.

A `MouseListener` is not really an appropriate listener to use for buttons, a better choice would be to use a `ActionListener` which takes into account mouse clicks and keyboard events...

See [How to write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [How to use buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more details...